# Can I replicate a table in PostgreSQL to an unlogged table in another database?

Tags: replication, postgresql-10

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createpublication.html) is not clear about this specific logical replication scenario. It does mention unlogged tables on the publisher's side:

> Only persistent base tables can be part of a publication. Temporary
>   tables, **unlogged tables**, foreign tables, materialized views, regular
>   views, and partitioned tables cannot be part of a publication. To
>   replicate a partitioned table, add the individual partitions to the
>   publication.

In my scenario, the table in the publisher is normal, while the table in the subscriber is unlogged.

Can I do this?

Comment: It sounds like you can.  have you tried?

Comment: Yes, and I got some erros, but they weren’t related in the end. I will try again soon